# adding an attribute in suds

Tags: python, web-services, suds

I have to do soap request with suds and Python

```
<soap:Body> 
    <registerOrder> 
        <order merchantOrderNumber="" description="" amount=""  currency=""  language=""  xmlns=""> 
             <returnUrl>http://mysafety.com</returnUrl> 
        </order> 
    </registerOrder> 
</soap:Body>
```

How to add an attribute in registerOrder?

Answer (score 8):

A more dynamic version of the MessagePlugin would be:

```
from suds.sax.attribute import Attribute
from suds.plugin import MessagePlugin

class _AttributePlugin(MessagePlugin):
    """
    Suds plug-in extending the method call with arbitrary attributes.
    """
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.kwargs = kwargs

    def marshalled(self, context):
        method = context.envelope.getChild('Body')[0]
        for key, item in self.kwargs.iteritems():
            method.attributes.append(Attribute(key, item))
```

Usage:

```
client = Client(url)
# method 1
client.options.plugins = [_AttributePlugin(foo='bar')]
response = client.service.method1()
client.options.plugins = []
# method 2
response = client.service.method2()
```

Answer (score 5):

In [suds documentation](https://fedorahosted.org/suds/wiki/Documentation) search for a MessagePlugin. The marshalled option is what you're searching for. You need to add it into your client as a plugin:

```
self.client = Client(url, plugins=[MyPlugin()])
```

In marshalled method search for context.envelope childs. The python's vars() function is very useful in this place. As I think, It should like something like this for you:

```
from suds.sax.attribute import Attribute
from suds.plugin import MessagePlugin
class MyPlugin(MessagePlugin):
    def marshalled(self, context):
        foo = context.envelope.getChild('Body').getChild('registerOrder')[0]
        foo.attributes.append(Attribute("foo", "bar"))
```

I was sitting at this for last week, so might it'll save some time for you :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the __inject Client option to inject a particular xml

```
raw_xml = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        ...
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>"""

print client.service.example(__inject={'msg':raw_xml})
```

Also, I prefer using suds-jurko https://pypi.python.org/pypi/suds-jurko/0.6 which is a fork of suds that is actively maintained.

Answer (score 1):

I have reused https://fedorahosted.org/suds/ticket/21 and have adapted the code to use the idea. Change SUDS as below and use

```
Client.<method>(param1=value1, ... , attributes={'attrName1':'attrVal1'} )
```

to call 'method' with the 'attrName1' attribute as wanted.

```
--- a/website/suds/bindings/binding.py
+++ b/website/suds/bindings/binding.py
@@ -24,6 +24,7 @@ from suds.sax import Namespace
 from suds.sax.parser import Parser
 from suds.sax.document import Document
 from suds.sax.element import Element
+from suds.sax.attribute import Attribute
 from suds.sudsobject import Factory, Object
 from suds.mx import Content
 from suds.mx.literal import Literal as MxLiteral
@@ -101,7 +102,7 @@ class Binding:
         """
         raise Exception, 'not implemented'

-    def get_message(self, method, args, kwargs):
+    def get_message(self, method, args, kwargs, attributes=None):
         """
         Get the soap message for the specified method, args and soapheaders.
         This is the entry point for creating the outbound soap message.
@@ -115,11 +116,23 @@ class Binding:
         @rtype: L{Document}
         """

+        if attributes:
+            pass
+            # moved to suds/bindings/document.py
+
+            #print method
+            #for name, val in attributes.items():
+            #    method.attributes.append(Attribute(name, val))
+
+
         content = self.headercontent(method)
         header = self.header(content)
-        content = self.bodycontent(method, args, kwargs)
+        content = self.bodycontent(method, args, kwargs, attributes=attributes)
         body = self.body(content)
         env = self.envelope(header, body)
+        #if attributes:
+        #    print content
+        #    1/0
         if self.options().prefixes:
             body.normalizePrefixes()
             env.promotePrefixes()
@@ -535,4 +548,4 @@ class PartElement(SchemaElement):
             return self
         else:
             return self.__resolved
-    
\ No newline at end of file
+    
diff --git a/website/suds/bindings/document.py b/website/suds/bindings/document.py
index edd9422..0c84753 100644
--- a/website/suds/bindings/document.py
+++ b/website/suds/bindings/document.py
@@ -38,7 +38,7 @@ class Document(Binding):
     (multiple message parts), must present a I{document} view for that method.
     """

-    def bodycontent(self, method, args, kwargs):
+    def bodycontent(self, method, args, kwargs, attributes=None):
         #
         # The I{wrapped} vs I{bare} style is detected in 2 ways.
         # If there is 2+ parts in the message then it is I{bare}.
@@ -54,6 +54,12 @@ class Document(Binding):
         else:
             root = []
         n = 0
+
+        if attributes:
+            #print root.__class__
+            for name, val in attributes.items():
+                root.set(name, val)
+
         for pd in self.param_defs(method):
             if n < len(args):
                 value = args[n]
diff --git a/website/suds/client.py b/website/suds/client.py
index 8b4f258..f80e36a 100644
--- a/website/suds/client.py
+++ b/website/suds/client.py
@@ -592,7 +592,10 @@ class SoapClient:
         timer.start()
         result = None
         binding = self.method.binding.input
-        soapenv = binding.get_message(self.method, args, kwargs)
+        attributes = kwargs.get('attributes', None)
+        if attributes:
+            del kwargs['attributes']
+        soapenv = binding.get_message(self.method, args, kwargs, attributes)
         timer.stop()
         metrics.log.debug(
                 "message for '%s' created: %s",
@@ -841,4 +844,4 @@ class RequestContext:
         @type error: A suds I{TransportError}.
         """
         return self.client.failed(self.binding, error)
-        
\ No newline at end of file
+
```